# Why is my theme not picked up? (and where to look to solve this)

Tags: theme, template

I'm working with Magento a few now, but I encounter a problem that I can't solve. I installed a new template/theme and made the required changes to the Design > Package tab in the configuration of my site. Flushed caches, disabled all custom extensions but the template is not picked up.

Magento keeps falling back to the Base template files. So I tried to tell Magento to use the RWD template, again with no result at all.

I'm out of options now, really don't know if I'm overlooking something, or if there is another place to search for.

Is there anybody who can point me in the right direction? I'm using 1.9.3.1

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please check permissions on folders?

Comment: I set the permissions according to Magento rules. Didn't help..

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to find the solution for this problem. I searched my database with the name of my previous theme and found out that there is a table called design_change. And there it was. All the websites in these rows pointed to the old, non existing theme. So I changed these rows to point to the correct theme and everything is working now.